# Oracle Apex versus Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

To the best of my knowledge, Oracle Apex looks similar to Oracle SQL Developer.  For all of my database development life, I have only used SQL Developer.

Are there any specific feature sets available in Apex that are available in developing Oracle databases that are not in SQL Developer, and visa versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

SQL Developper is a GUI tool to run ad hoc queries, develop stored procedures and similar,  more like a GUI version of, command line tool, sqlplus.

On the other hand Apex is more for prototyping/developping some custom applications that some end user (or admin) would access using the browser (HTML interface).

Comment: Thanks for the welcome.  I have been lurking for some time, but this is the first question that I could not answer by querying Google.

So, I am not missing out on anything spectacular then.

Comment: @adv There is a big difference between apex and sql dev, as igr pointed out. Sure you can browse database objects, edit them, and run sql, but it is still far from sql dev functionality in that regard. It is useful however for apex developers. And no, you're not missing out on something spectacular if all you were looking for was an sql dev ide replacement as apex is targeted at web application development.